# ASP.NET Core Identity 2: User.IsInRole always returns false

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

**The question:** I call `RoleManager.CreateAsync()` and `RoleManager.AddClaimAsync()` to create roles and associated role claims. Then I call `UserManager.AddToRoleAsync()` to add users to those roles. But when the user logs in, neither the roles nor the associated claims show up in the `ClaimsPrincipal` (i.e. the Controller's `User` object). The upshot of this is that `User.IsInRole()` always returns false, and the collection of Claims returned by `User.Claims` doesn't contain the role claims, and the `[Authorize(policy: xxx)]` annotations don't work.

I should also add that one solution is to revert from using the new `services.AddDefaultIdentity()` (which is provided by the templated code) back to calling `services.AddIdentity().AddSomething().AddSomethingElse()`. I don't want to go there, because I've seen too many conflicting stories online about what I need to do to configure `AddIdentity` for various use cases. `AddDefaultIdentity` seems to do most things correctly without a lot of added fluent configuration.

BTW, I'm asking this question with the intention of answering it... unless someone else gives me a better answer than the one I'm prepared to post. I'm also asking this question because **after several weeks of searching I have yet to find a good end-to-end example of creating and using Roles and Claims in ASP.NET Core Identity 2**. Hopefully, the code example in this question might help someone else who stumbles upon it...

**The setup:**
I created a new ASP.NET Core Web Application, select Web Application (Model-View-Controller), and change the Authentication to Individual User Accounts.  In the resultant project, I do the following:

- In Package Manager Console, update the database to match the scaffolded migration:

  > update-database
- Add an `ApplicationUser` class that extends `IdentityUser`.  This involves adding the class, adding a line of code to the `ApplicationDbContext` and replacing every instance of `<IdentityUser>` with `<ApplicationUser>` everywhere in the project.

  The new `ApplicationUser` class:

  ```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  {
      public string FullName { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  The updated `ApplicationDbContext` class:

  ```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
  {
      public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
          : base(options)
      { }

      // Add this line of code
      public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- In Package Manager Console, create a new migration and update the database to incorporate the `ApplicationUsers` entity.

  > add-migration m_001
  >   update-database
- Add the following line of code in `Startup.cs` to enable `RoleManager`

  ```
  services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
      .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() // <-- Add this line
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
  ```
- Add some code to seed roles, claims, and users.  The basic concept for this sample code is that I have two claims: `can_report` allows the holder to create reports, and `can_test` allows the holder to run tests. I have two Roles, `Admin` and `Tester`.  The `Tester` role can run tests, but can't create reports. The `Admin` role can do both. So, I add the claims to the roles, and create one `Admin` test user and one `Tester` test user.

  First, I add a class whose sole purpose in life is to contain constants used elsewhere in this example:

  ```
  // Contains constant strings used throughout this example
  public class MyApp
  {
      // Claims
      public const string CanTestClaim = "can_test";
      public const string CanReportClaim = "can_report";

      // Role names
      public const string AdminRole = "admin";
      public const string TesterRole = "tester";

      // Authorization policy names
      public const string CanTestPolicy = "can_test";
      public const string CanReportPolicy = "can_report";
  }
  ```

  Next, I seed my roles, claims, and users. I put this code in the main landing page controller just for expedience; it really belongs in the "startup" `Configure` method, but that's an extra half-dozen lines of code...

  ```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
      const string Password = "QwertyA1?";

      const string AdminEmail = "admin@example.com";
      const string TesterEmail = "tester@example.com";

      private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
      private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

      // Constructor (DI claptrap)
      public HomeController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
      {
          _roleManager = roleManager;
          _userManager = userManager;
      }

      public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
      {
          // Initialize roles
          if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(MyApp.AdminRole)) {
              var role = new IdentityRole(MyApp.AdminRole);
              await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
              await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim(MyApp.CanTestClaim, ""));
              await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim(MyApp.CanReportClaim, ""));
          }

          if (!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(MyApp.TesterRole)) {
              var role = new IdentityRole(MyApp.TesterRole);
              await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
              await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(role, new Claim(MyApp.CanTestClaim, ""));
          }

          // Initialize users
          var qry = _userManager.Users;
          IdentityResult result;

          if (await qry.Where(x => x.UserName == AdminEmail).FirstOrDefaultAsync() == null) {
              var user = new ApplicationUser {
                  UserName = AdminEmail,
                  Email = AdminEmail,
                  FullName = "Administrator"
              };

              result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Password);
              if (!result.Succeeded) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Join(" | ", result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description)));

              result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, MyApp.AdminRole);
              if (!result.Succeeded) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Join(" | ", result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description)));
          }

          if (await qry.Where(x => x.UserName == TesterEmail).FirstOrDefaultAsync() == null) {
              var user = new ApplicationUser {
                  UserName = TesterEmail,
                  Email = TesterEmail,
                  FullName = "Tester"
              };

              result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Password);
              if (!result.Succeeded) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Join(" | ", result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description)));

              result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, MyApp.TesterRole);
              if (!result.Succeeded) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Join(" | ", result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description)));
          }

          // Roles and Claims are in a cookie. Don't expect to see them in
          // the same request that creates them (i.e., the request that
          // executes the above code to create them). You need to refresh
          // the page to create a round-trip that includes the cookie.
          var admin = User.IsInRole(MyApp.AdminRole);
          var claims = User.Claims.ToList();

          return View();
      }

      [Authorize(policy: MyApp.CanTestPolicy)]
      public IActionResult Test()
      {
          return View();
      }

      [Authorize(policy: MyApp.CanReportPolicy)]
      public IActionResult Report()
      {
          return View();
      }

      [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
      public IActionResult Error()
      {
          return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
      }
  }
  ```

  and I register my authentication policies in the "Startup" `ConfigureServices` routine, just after the call to `services.AddMvc`

  ```
      // Register authorization policies
      services.AddAuthorization(options => {
          options.AddPolicy(MyApp.CanTestPolicy,   policy => policy.RequireClaim(MyApp.CanTestClaim));
          options.AddPolicy(MyApp.CanReportPolicy, policy => policy.RequireClaim(MyApp.CanReportClaim));
      });
  ```

Whew. Now, (assuming I've noted all of the applicable code I've added to the project, above), when I run the app, I notice that neither of my "built-in" test users can access either the `/home/Test` or `/home/Report` page. Moreover, if I set a breakpoint in the Index method, I see that my roles and claims do not exist in the `User` object. But I can look at the database and see all of the roles and claims are there.

Comment: How is the user authenticating?  None of your code indicates how the app could possibly know who the current user is.

Comment: The user logs in. That is part of the code I get from the template.

Comment: Is there a claim containing the user id?

Comment: When a user logs in, the `User.Claims` list contains `nameidentifier` (a GUID with punctuation [dashes]), `name` (the username), and `SecurityStamp` (a GUID without punctuation). But, because I've associated a Role with the user, and the role has associated claims, I should also see those claims in the collection.  (You'll have to wait for the answer to find out why my custom claims aren't there. ;)

Comment: Did u try adding custom claims

Comment: Just because a relationship exists between user and roles does not mean you should see the associated claims.  You can add the claims to the auth cookie on sign-in (but this could result in a very big cookie)...or you can load the claims on each request in custom middleware...or you can add the claims via a custom `IClaimsTransformation` implementation.

Comment: @Brad But if I call `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "my_role")` then I would expect `User.IsInRole("my_role")` to return true when that user logs in. And I would expect `[Authorize(Roles = "my_role")]` to work. Neither work because the role claim isn't in the auth cookie.

Comment: @t-prisar Yes, calling `await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(myUser, new Claim("some_claim_name", "some_claim_value"));` persists the claim in the Identity database and the claim shows up in the cookie (and the `User.Claims` collection). It's only roles and role claims that don't make it from the Identity database into the auth cookie.

Comment: Why should UserManager be responsible for anything to do with authentication?  Your expectations are irrelevant.

Comment: @bob the problem is most probably in `services.AddAuthorization(...)`

Comment: @bob did u check whether the role is present in claimsprincipal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, to recap, the question asks why the code provided by the ASP.NET Core Web Application template doesn't load roles or role claims into the cookie when a user logs in.

After much Googling and experimenting, there appear to be two modifications that must be made to the templated code in order to get Roles and Role Claims to work:

First, you must add the following line of code in Startup.cs to enable RoleManager. (This bit of magic was mentioned in the OP.)

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
   .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() // <-- Add this line
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

But wait, there's more! According to [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-420066501), getting the roles and claims to show up in the cookie involves *either* reverting to the `service.AddIdentity` initialization code, or sticking with `service.AddDefaultIdentity` and adding this line of code to `ConfigureServices`:

```
// Add Role claims to the User object
// See: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813#issuecomment-420066501
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>>();
```

If you read the discussion referenced above, you'll see that Roles and Role Claims are apparently kind-of-deprecated, or at least not eagerly supported. Personally, I find it really useful to assign claims to roles, assign roles to users, and then make authorization decisions based on the claims (which are granted to the users based on their roles). This gives me an easy, declarative way to allow, for example, one function to be accessed by multiple roles (i.e. all of the roles that contain the claim used to enable that function).

But you DO want to pay attention to the amount of role and claim data being carried in the auth cookie. More data means more bytes sent to the server with each request, and I have no clue what happens when you bump up against some sort of limit to the cookie size.

Answer (score 5):

Ahh, there are some changes from ASP.NET Core version 2.0 to 2.1. `AddDefaultIdentity` is the one.

I don't know where to start from your code, so, I will provide an example to create and get user role(s).

Let's create `UserRoles` first:

```
public enum UserRoles
{
    [Display(Name = "Quản trị viên")]
    Administrator = 0,

    [Display(Name = "Kiểm soát viên")]
    Moderator = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Thành viên")]
    Member = 2
}
```

*Note*: You can remove the attribute `Display`.

Then, we create `RolesExtensions` class:

```
public static class RolesExtensions
{
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        foreach (string roleName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(UserRoles)))
        {
            if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName))
            {
                await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, in the `Startup.cs` class, we run it:

```
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env, 
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        // other settings...

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        var task = RolesExtensions.InitializeAsync(roleManager);
        task.Wait();
    }
```

*Note*: `Configure` requires a returned type `void`, so we need to create a task to initialize the user roles and we call `Wait` method.

**Do not** change the returned type like this:

```
public async void Configure(...)
{
    await RolesExtensions.InitializeAsync(roleManager);
}
```

Source: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

In the `ConfigureServices` method, these configurations would NOT *work* (we cannot use `User.IsInRole` correctly):

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    //.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    //.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I don't know why but `AddRoles` and `AddRoleManager` don't support to check role for a user (`User.IsInRole`).

In this case, we need to register service like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

By using this way, we create 3 user roles in the databse:

[image: 1]

When register new user, we just need to call:

```
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, nameof(UserRoles.Administrator));
```

---

Finally, we can use `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` and:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    // authorized
}

// or
if (User.IsInRole(nameof(UserRoles.Administrator)))
{
    // authorized
}

// but
if (User.IsInRole("ADMINISTRATOR"))
{
    // authorized
}
```

P/S: There are a lot things which need to be implement to achieve this goal. So maybe I missed something in this example.

Comment: Hey Tan, great answer. I guess I should have added that I want to use the newfangled `services.AddDefaultIdentity` rather than `services.AddIdentity()…` because I've seen too many conflicting stories online about what fluent methods need to follow `AddIdentity` to get it to work for various use cases.

Comment: Also, I think that your call to InitializeAsync my be prone to deadlock issues in ASP.NET.  Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097498/1637105). This issue of calling an async method from the synchronous Startup methods is why my example code put all of the seed logic into the Controller code (so I wouldn't have to include the extra code needed to do it correctly from the Startup code).

Answer (score 2):

If I use “Roles” instead of ClaimTypes.Role in **.net6 blazor wasm** , @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] not work and get this error in browser console :

RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (admin)”

By using of ClaimTypes.Role the problem resolved :

```
private async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaimsAsync(User user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>()
    {
        new Claim("UserName", user.Email),
        new Claim("FullName", user.FirstName+" "+user.LastName),
    };
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    foreach (var role in roles)
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)); // this line

    return claims;
}
```

https://github.com/mammadkoma/Attendance/blob/master/Attendance/Server/Controllers/AccountsController.cs

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to fix Authentication like this

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` to `AddDefaultIdentity`, if you have a custom `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` you may also have to change its construction to reflect Roles:

```
    // Change this ------>
    public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            // Add this ------>
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
           // Change this ------>
           : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
        }
    
        protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            // Add Claims
            return identity;
        }
    }
```