# The Authorize attribute in ASP.NET Core WebAPI controller with the Roles is not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I tried using `[Authorize(Roles="role")]` on my controller, but it doesn't work. Later, I checked using `IsInRole` to confirm if the role was successfully added, but it always shows false.

However, I found an article that had previously addressed this problem, so I tried the suggested solution, but it still didn't work.

[ASP.NET Core Identity 2: User.IsInRole always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271496/asp-net-core-identity-2-user-isinrole-always-returns-false)

I would like you to help me identify any issues in my code.

`user.IsInRole("Developer")` is return `false`, but `_userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user1, "Developer")` is return `ture`.

```
var user = HttpContext.User;
var ss = user.IsInRole("Developer"); // return false
var user1 = await _userManager.Users
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name));
var sss = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user1, "Developer");  // return true
```

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
            {
                opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                opt.Password.RequiredLength = 0;
                opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>,UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser, IdentityRole>>();
```

Here is my user registration process.

```
if (await _userManager.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == registerDto.Username))
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("username", "Username taken");
   return ValidationProblem();
}

var user = new AppUser
{
   DisplayName = registerDto.DisplayName,
   UserName = registerDto.Username
};
var role = registerDto.Role;

if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
{
   var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerDto.Password);

   if (result.Succeeded == false)
   {
       return BadRequest(result.Errors);
   }

   await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
   return await CreateUserObject(user);
}

return BadRequest($"Role {role} not found");
```

Updete:
It's `AspNetRoles` table.
[image]

Update 2:
My others setting.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
            {
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
                opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) &&
                            HubPath.CheckStartsWithSegments(path))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(opt =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Comment: Is the value in the Database correct?

Comment: @QiangFu Yes, this the table content of AspNetRoles.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code for a test.(.net6 api project)
AspNetIdentityDbContext.cs

```
    public class AspNetIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=192.168.2.68;database=wa99UserAuth;user=mysql1;password=Q!q11111", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()));
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AspNetIdentityDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AspNetIdentityDbContext>();
```

controller

```
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public ValuesController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this._userManager = userManager;
            this._roleManager = roleManager;
            this._signInManager = signInManager;
        }


        [HttpPost("AddRole")]
        public async Task<string> AddRole(string role)
        {
            var role2 = new IdentityRole { Name = role };         
            var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role2);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return "Succeed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<string> register(string username,string password,string role)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = username
            };

            if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role))
            {
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
                    return "Succeed";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Error";
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<string> login(string username,string password)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return "Succeed";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error";
            }
        }

        [Authorize(Roles = "Developer")]
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public async Task test()
        {
            var user = HttpContext.User;
            var ss = user.IsInRole("Developer"); 
            var user1 = await _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == "user1");
            var sss = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user1, "Developer");  
        }
    }
```

Test:
1.Add a role name "Developer"
[image]
2.Register a user "testUser" password "Q@q11111" with role "Developer"
[image]
3.Signin the user
[image]
4.Run test ,ss is true
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, when I modify `AddIdentityCore` to `AddIdentity`, I consistently encounter the error message, `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` BTW, My DataContext is `DataContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, IdentityRole, string>`.

Comment: I added others code.

Comment: Now, I have fixed my issue. In fact, the issue was related to the JWT settings. I found a sample and compared it with my code. I made some modifications to my code based on the sample, and it resolved the problem. Although I don't fully understand the reasons behind those changes, they helped resolve the issue. https://github.com/DevBugFix/dotnetCore_5_Idenity_token